# Cancel Download using WWW::Mechanize in Perl

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I have written a Perl script which would check a list of URLs and connect to them by sending a GET request.

Now, let's say that one of these URLs has a file which is very big in size, for instance, has a size > 100 MB.

When a request is sent to download this file using this:

```
$mech=WWW::Mechanize->new();
$url="http://somewebsitename.com/very_big_file.txt"
$mech->get($url)
```

Once the GET request is sent, it will start downloading the file. I want this to be cancelled using WWW::Mechanize. How can I do that?

I checked the documentation of this Perl Module here:

http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize

However, I could not find a method which would help me do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Under what condition would it get canceled?

Comment: I want to cancel the request based on the size of HTTP Response and read the next URL from the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Aborting a `GET` request

Using the `:content_cb` option, you can provide a callback function to `get()` that will be executed for each chunk of response content received from the server. You can set<sup>*</sup> the chunk size (in bytes) using the `:read_size_hint` option. These options are documented in [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#REQUEST_METHODS) (`get()` in WWW::Mechanize is just an overloaded version of the same method in LWP::UserAgent).

The following request will be aborted after reading 1024 bytes of response content:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

sub callback {
    my ($data, $response, $protocol) = @_;

    die "Too much data";
}

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

my $url = 'http://www.example.com';

$mech->get($url, ':content_cb' => \&callback, ':read_size_hint' => 1024);

print $mech->response()->header('X-Died');
```

#### Output:

```
Too much data at ./mechanize line 12.
```

Note that the `die` in the callback does not cause the program itself to die; it simply sets the `X-Died` header in the response object. You can add the appropriate logic to your callback to determine under what conditions a request should be aborted.

### Don't even fetch URL if content is too large

Based on your comments, it sounds like what you *really* want is to never send a request in the first place if the content is too large. This is quite different from aborting a `GET` request midway through, since you can fetch the `Content-Length` header with a `HEAD` request and perform different actions based on the value:

```
my @urls = qw(http://www.example.com http://www.google.com);

foreach my $url (@urls) {
    $mech->head($url);

    if ($mech->success) {
        my $length = $mech->response()->header('Content-Length') // 0;

        next if $length > 1024;

        $mech->get($url);
    }
}
```

Note that according to the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), applications *should* set the `Content-Length` header. This does not mean that they *will* (hence the default value of `0` in my code example).

---

* According to the documentation, the "protocol module which will try to read data from the server in chunks of this size," but I don't think it's guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Since I am going through a list of URLs, I would like to skip to the next URL in the list when I observe that the size of HTTP response (Content-Length response header) is greater than some threshold. Is it possible to go to the next URL in the list instead of using a callback function? I would just need to do something like next() in the loop to cancel the current request and read the next URL from the list.

Comment: Cancelling a request midway (your original question) and just not making a request in the first place are *totally* different. You can use the `HEAD` method to just get the headers for each URL and check the `Content-Length`. If too large, skip to the next URL; otherwise, send a `GET` request.